# Azure DevOps Test Configuration Variables in Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I see in Azure DevOps, we can set different test configurations. Under each configuration, there are variables that we can add.

How can I access these variables in a pipeline? Is there a reason for variables since I have not seen anything from Microsoft addressing them in pipelines running unit tests.

Comment: Are you talking about the test plans feature? That's for manual testing. It has no relationship with pipelines.

Comment: @DanielMann it's the test plan configurations. Under it, it has configurations I can add (wtih variables). How can I access these variables in a pipeline?

Comment: The test plans feature is for **manual** testing. If you want to access test plan values in pipelines, that's not really a supported scenario and you'll have to write your own integration using the REST APIs. You should really just create variable templates per environment and load them in the appropriate stage. Don't try to use test plans for this.

Comment: It is just that I am running VSTests in my pipeline. It has different strategies in which each strategy is tied to a config. It'd be nice to just tie it all together and have each stage grab the appropriate variables.